# Sinch shouldSendPushNotifications on iOS invoked when the app is in foreground

Tags: ios, sinch

I have the following scenario:

**iPhoneA & iPhoneB:** sinch client initialized with message support and Push Support enabled, both app in foreground;
**iPhoneA send message to iPhoneB:** before the Message Sent and Delivery Callback, the shouldSendPushNotifications was invoked.
The message was received correctly and I can view correctly.

I tried to create a new sinch app and new user, but the result is the same.

On Android all seems to works correctly.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct it should invoke shouldSendPushNotifications if you have not  called startListeningOnActiveConnection, using only push is the chapest way of using sinch.

Comment: We have called "startListeningOnACtiveConnection", and we also tried to disable push notifications by calling setsupportPushNotification. the result is the same, we always receive a callback shouldSendPushNotifications.
Is there a complete example for messaging system on Sinch? We are using sandobx environment.

Comment: Before you removed the push, did you call unregisterPushData?

Comment: A tuturial is on its way. we are proof Reading it now.